# why do my object files look weird when imported to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, 3d, rendering, .obj

I have made some heart models on medical software Materialise Mimics and have exported them as .obj files because the software doesnt support exporting as .fbx.

I've tried other Unity developed programs with the exact same models and they look really good, but I dont know what they've done to process the files.

I'm quite new to unity and have tried following some guides on making materials and shaders, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

[Object file in 3D viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiYsM.jpg)

[Object file directly imported to Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XkJb.jpg)

[Object file with Material added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFirk.jpg)

Comment: Looks like it’s bringing its own light with it

Answer (score 0):

I think the model's normals got inverted. Try using a double sided shader like this https://gist.github.com/naojitaniguchi/62ccf37c801ea55517b7 (not mine) and see if it's works
I hope it do

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit stuck, I've been searching for the issue but I cant seem to find much on it.
Basically, I copy the Github code into a c# script, but then I get the error message "warning CS1633: Unrecognized #pragma directive"
I read that this is because some of the script might be using unity script code instead of c#
Let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: this isn't a .cs script this is a .shader file. probably by changing the file type will solve it.